# How to work with Azure Devops Deployment Pools via ReST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get%20agent%20pools?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0]

The above document indicates that Deployment pools should be included.  Unfortunately, they are not returned (although all of the "automation" pools are.

So how does one programmatically list, get (by id) and create/update these pools????

[image]

UPDATE....

Capturing network traces while viewing  /_settings/deploymentpools?view=pool

has revealed that there is a ReST call to _apis/distributedtask/deploymentPools

which displays the proper information.  HOWEVER, continued searching of learn.microsoft.com does not provide any information on this rest call.

UPDATE 2:  Returned (sanitized) JSON for call Matt recommended:

[image]

JSON from _apis/distributedtask/deploymentPools/deploymentPoolsSummary?expands=2&api-version=6.1-preview.1

[image]

As can be seen, the two are not equivalent and so far only the call reverse engineered from the UI shows the same information set (including 2 needed fields related to online and offline counts)

Comment: Can you include some details about what pools you have (shown from UI) vs. what is returned by the API?

Comment: It is difficult as the information is largely properietary.... 

Groups are OK.  dev.azure.com/org/proj/_machinegroup?view=MachineGroupView  from the UI...

But there does not appear to be a documented analog for the underlying Pools (which are at the org level) and found in the UI @ 
 dev.azure.com/org//_settings/deploymentpools?view=pool 

Substitude in your own org and project and you can see the relevant pages in the UI.

Comment: It helps if you can show something like "Pool A" is visible from the UI but not visible from the API, here is the API call I made to show it.  If you have result differences between the API and the UI, it could be because of security on your PAT vs. your UI login.  As it stands, the results of the API match with what I have configured in count and value.

Comment: @Matt - Please see update...  You will get a match on Deployment Groups, but NOT on Pools.

Answer (score 1):

Given this example Pool configuration:

[image]

When utilizing the [Pool API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get%20agent%20pools?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) without any filters using this script:

```
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=6.0"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty value | 
    Select-Object name, poolType
```

Returns:

```
name                            poolType  
----                            --------  
Default                         automation
Hosted                          automation
Hosted VS2017                   automation
Hosted Windows Container        automation
Hosted macOS                    automation
Hosted Ubuntu 1604              automation
Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019 automation
Hosted macOS High Sierra        automation
Azure Pipelines                 automation
```

It seems like the default without filters adds an implied filter for automation poolType as you suggested.  Adding a filter targeting deployment pools though I think gets the result you are expecting:

```
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=6.0&poolType=deployment"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty value | 
    Select-Object name, poolType
```

Returns:

```
name        poolType  
----        --------  
ExamplePool deployment
```

Comment: Interesting.... What is suprising is that the UI fores NOT use that call with the filter...  Instead it uses a call from version 6.1-preview.1 of

https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentPools?api-version=6.1-Preview1

This call is NOT documented (as far as I can tell) @ learn.microsoft.com, but once it was discovered, it can be seen to be used in multiple extensions and other places....

So that leaves an open question of what is the *supported* (i.e. documented) method????

Comment: I wouldn't worry overmuch about how the UI loads it.  If the API call I show here with the filter gets you the details you want, that is the one you should use as.  It is the supported/documented one.  If anything, it just has a bug or undocumented "feature" to only source the "automation" pool types by default.  I raised a bug about it on the developercommunity.

Comment: Thanks... Please see "UPDATE 2".... The response content between the two calls are different.  Looking at other things it seems a fair amount of api-version=6.1-preview.1 may not be publicly documented.

Answer (score 1):

> including 2 needed fields related to online and offline counts

We can use the Rest API to List Deployment Pools, get the deployment status via field `onlineAgentsCount` and `offlineAgentsCount` and get `pool ID`.

API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentPools/deploymentPoolsSummary?expands=2
```

Result:

[image]

And get the deployment pool detail or update deployment pool via this API

API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?poolIds={pool ID}&api-version=6.0
```

**Update1**

The Microsoft doc does not list all REST APIs, but we can capture these APIs via F12 or fiddler. In addition, you can also try this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), it will also show Deployment pool info.

In addition, you can raise a new suggestion ticket to the [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), Microsoft Azure DevOps Teams will check it.

Comment: Vito, thanks for the response... Yes, I already covered the existence of that API call. My issue is that *it is not documented* (at least I could not find it) and was only discoverable by examination of traces while running the application and loading the page.

Comment: Hi @DavidV.Corbin, I have updated the answer, please check it and then kindly share the latest news here. Thanks.

Comment: Vito - the issue with learn.microsoft.com not officially supporting a given rest call is that using it incurs additional risk as it could literally go away at any time. I have been in touch this the PG about this (though for a completely different set of calls related to non-YAML Release Pipeline Definitions).

Comment: Hi @DavidV.Corbin, There is currently no official documentation that supports this API. We can't be sure if this API will change, as a workaround, you can use this API to work temporarily and re-capture it again if it has changed. By the way, do you mind accepting the answer temporarily? And we could archive this thread. You could keep touching with product team, If any updates, you could kindly share the answer here and re-accept the answer. Thanks